# Submit Form after validation buttons has to be hit twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't have access to the php file so I have to validate using JavaScript. I decided to use jQuery with it. I do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#targetForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        closeOpenBoxes();
    });
});
function closeOpenBoxes(){
    if($('.missingBox:visible').length > 0){
        $('.missingBox:visible').slideUp('fast', function(){
            validateForm();
        });
    }
    else{
        validateForm();
    }
}
function validateForm(){
    if($('#first_name').val() == ''){
        $('#firstNameBox').slideDown();
    }
    else{
        if($('#last_name').val() == ''){
            $('#lastNameBox').slideDown();
        }
        else{
            if($('#company').val() == ''){
                $('#companyBox').slideDown();
            }
            else{
                if($('#country').val() == ''){
                    $('#countryBox').slideDown();
                }
                else{
                    if($('#email').val() == ''){
                        $('#emailBox').slideDown();
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#targetForm').unbind();
                        $('#targetForm').submit();                  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



}
```

It works, but for the form to actually submit after validation, you have to hit the submit button twice. I tried a few different things like adding `return true` to the end of my functions and even putting a timeout on the submit so the `e.preventDefault()` would completely unbind before before the `submit` would fire after validation like this and it still didn't work:

```
$('#targetForm').unbind();
setTimeout(function(){$('#targetForm').submit()},1000);
```

I made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uXg3R/1/ I'm not sure what I'm missing any help would be awesome

Comment: I would be using `case` statements for this, not these nested ifs...

Comment: How would I use a case for multiple text inputs? Any adjustment to the code is welcome.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use a validation framework like `parsleyjs`

Comment: I've actually never seen this Parsley framework. Looks really awesome, i need to check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ONLY way I was able to get this to work was making TWO FORMS, one hidden and one visible and this ridiculously repetitive JS.

```
<form id="targetForm">
    <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="hidden" />
</form>

<form id="visibleForm" name="visibleForm">
    <label for="first_nameVisible">First Name<span class="required">*</span></label><br />
    <input id="first_nameVisible" class="textInput" maxlength="40" name="first_nameVisible" size="20" type="text" /><br />
    <div class="missingBox" id="firstNameBox">
        First Name is Required!
    </div>
</form>
```

And My JS:

```
 $('#submitBtn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('.missingBox:visible').length > 0) {
            $('.missingBox:visible').slideUp('fast', function () {
                if ($('#first_nameVisible').val() == '') {
                    $('#firstNameBox').slideDown();
                } else {
                    $('#first_name').val($('#first_nameVisible').val());
                    setTimeout(function(){$('#targetForm').submit()},700);
                }
            });
        }
        else{
             $('#first_name').val($('#first_nameVisible').val());
             setTimeout(function(){$('#targetForm').submit()},700);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the 'if' on the target form. Instead of

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#targetForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        closeOpenBoxes();
    });
});
function closeOpenBoxes(){
    if($('.missingBox:visible').length > 0){
        $('.missingBox:visible').slideUp('fast', function(){
            validateForm();
        });
    }
    else{
        validateForm();
    }
}
function validateForm(){
    if($('#first_name').val() == ''){
        $('#firstNameBox').slideDown();
    }
    else{
        if($('#last_name').val() == ''){
            $('#lastNameBox').slideDown();
        }
        else{
            if($('#company').val() == ''){
                $('#companyBox').slideDown();
            }
            else{
                if($('#country').val() == ''){
                    $('#countryBox').slideDown();
                }
                else{
                    if($('#email').val() == ''){
                        $('#emailBox').slideDown();
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#targetForm').unbind();
                        $('#targetForm').submit();                  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Use

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#targetForm').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            closeOpenBoxes();
        });
    });
    function closeOpenBoxes(){
        if($('.missingBox:visible').length > 0){
            $('.missingBox:visible').slideUp('fast', function(){
                validateForm();
            });
        }
        else{
            validateForm();
        }
    }
    function validateForm(){
        if($('#first_name').val() == ''){
            $('#firstNameBox').slideDown();
        }
        else{
            if($('#last_name').val() == ''){
                $('#lastNameBox').slideDown();
            }
            else{
                if($('#company').val() == ''){
                    $('#companyBox').slideDown();
                }
                else{
                    if($('#country').val() == ''){
                        $('#countryBox').slideDown();
                    }
                    else{
                        if($('#email').val() == ''){
                            $('#emailBox').slideDown();
                        }
                        else{
                           if $('#targetForm').unbind();
                            $('#targetForm').submit();                  
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }



    }
```

Comment: -1, `if $('#targetForm').unbind();` makes no sense whatsoever.  You clearly don't know what `unbind()` means or how to construct `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Let your submit-action return eiter true or false if the form is valid or not.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#targetForm').submit(function (e) {
        return closeOpenBoxes();
    });
});

function closeOpenBoxes() {
    $('.missingBox:visible').slideUp('fast');
    return validateForm();
}
```

And in your validateForm:

```
.....
if ($('#email').val() == '') {
    $('#emailBox').slideDown();
} else {
    return true;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uXg3R/1/

Comment: Same behavior as original

Answer (score 0):

Remove e.preventDefault(); from your submit function and at validateForm function return false if a val is empty or undefinied and replace the following code:

```
$('#targetForm').unbind();
$('#targetForm').submit();
```

by
    return true;

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated JFiddle for you with the correct code, working properly http://jsfiddle.net/uXg3R/7/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#targetForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        closeOpenBoxes();
    });
});

function closeOpenBoxes() {
    if ($('.missingBox:visible').length > 0) {
        $('.missingBox:visible').slideUp('fast', function () {
            validateForm();
        });
    } else {
        validateForm();
    }
}

function validateForm() {
    if ($('#first_name').val() == '') {
        $('#firstNameBox').slideDown();
    } else {
        if ($('#last_name').val() == '') {
            $('#lastNameBox').slideDown();
        } else {
            if ($('#company').val() == '') {
                $('#companyBox').slideDown();
            } else {
                if ($('#country').val() == '') {
                    $('#countryBox').slideDown();
                } else {
                    if ($('#email').val() == '') {
                        $('#emailBox').slideDown();
                    } else {
                        if $('#targetForm').unbind();
                        $('#targetForm').submit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Simply needed to add an if statement at the bottom of your code in front of $('targetForm').unbind();

Comment: jsfiddle link is submitting without validating. Guess you missed something

Comment: yea, not sure why it is breaking the validation.. will edit post when that's fixed.